# Threadsafety with 'before' and 'after' state for fields/values in Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, thread-safety

I have a problem with "transactional" mutation of a thread-unsafe field of a class.
There are two kinds of threads accessing this field.

- one Mutation Logic Thread (Main Thread)
- *n* HTTP Request Threads

What I want is that as long as the main thread has access to the field all other threads (the request threads) should only be allowed to retrieve the state *before* the main thread accesses and mutates it.

Simply put:

- field = *10*
- mutation thread picks up field to mutate it to *5*
- meanwhile http request thread accesses field and receives *10*
- mutation thread finishes and sets field to *5*
- meanwhile http request thread accesses field and receives *5*

What I have currently is that the mutating thread is changing the field several times with different values. Between these mutations a HTTP request might drop in and retrieve the *current* state of the field which only might be temporary and therefore in my domain is a "wrong" state.

I know what I am asking for is in principle a *transaction*. However I'd like to make it work as simple as possible.

Comment: Why not set the actual field only at the end of your main thread's "transaction"? (and using a volatile field)

Comment: Well making the "transaction" manually is surely an option for me but at the current state of the application bound to a lot of changes in the codebase itself. Therefore I thought having some built-in features might help to be quicker

Comment: Using a volatile field (at least what Kotlin describes for it) would counter the use-case I have here. I don't want the HTTP threads to pickup a state of the mid-mutation process. Imagine there are about 50 state changes happening until the "transaction" is considered finished. I do not want the HTTP Threads to pickup one of those intermediate states

Comment: I think the idea is for the mutator thread to store any intermediate values in a private variable. Other threads continue to read unmodified field value. Once the mutator thread completes the computation, it updates the field using either volatile, atomics, or synchronization

Comment: ^^ And if you have multiple fields, encapsulate that state in an object and copy that object to variables local to the mutator thread. That way you only have to publish one object to the request threads when ready.

Comment: @peterz yes, that's what I meant by only setting the actual field at the end

Comment: @xetra11 I meant to use volatile only for the field that you want to really set at the end of the transaction (so you don't run into other problems). For intermediate states, just don't use that field, use a private one